# What is the real use of strnlen?

Tags: c++, c

I didn't understand what is the real use of strnlen(). can any one please let me know the practical uses or point me to a link where I can find the real uses?

Comment: What part of the documentation didn't you understand?

Comment: Note that `strnlen` is not in C standard. It's in POSIX and C11's equivalent is `strnlen_s` (from Annex K). BTW I don't get why there are some many downvotes, it's pretty valid question.

Comment: This question is not particularly high-quality, but it's valid and answerable. The abundance of downvotes and votes to close are unwarranted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You use strnlen to find the length of a string that might not contain a zero.

As an example, you might have a buffer of bytes read in from the network. The buffer is supposed to contain a string. But it might not! In this example you don't want to modify the buffer by writing a zero into the end, so you use strnlen to find the length of it as a string.

Comment: Put another way, it makes a bad stab at guessing since C does not have a string type.  It is not possible, in general to find how many bytes are read from networks by examining the buffer, which is why such network read calls always return th numbr of bytes received, (or an error).

Comment: @MartinJames: I think you missed the point in my example. The buffer is *supposed* to contain a string. But input from outside the program should *always* be untrusted. So the program doesn't know if there's a zero in it or not.

Comment: Network buffers don't contain strings, just arrays of bytes.

Comment: @MartinJames: If the protocol says it is supposed to contain a string, then it does. Or it might. The point is, you check it, then use it as a string.

Comment: @MartinJames: If it makes you happier, lets say the network buffer contains a series of strings separated by zero bytes. That gives you a good use for strnlen.

Comment: I think you just picked a bad example.  Typical TCP network buffers contain streams of bytes.  You cannot parse such data into 'strings' in any direct manner with either strlen(), strnlen() or anything else.  For example the rx buffer may contain the last char of one string, (null), 30 other complete strings and the first four chars of an incomplete string.  strlen() and strnlen() will both return 0.

Answer (score 11):

There are two major uses for `strnlen`:

1. Your input is a character array that might not be null-terminated if it the contents fill the whole array, and you want to determine the length of the "string" (not a C string).
2. Your input is guaranteed by the interface contract to be a valid C string, but with no limit on the size, and you want to impose a limit on the size without consuming disproportionate processing resources computing the size to check it against your limit.

In my opinion, case 1 is less interesting because you can usually deal with it just by making your buffer one byte larger and always storing a terminator in the last byte. Case 2 is much more interesting. For example, if your function starts with:

```
if (strlen(input) >= 256) return error_code;
```

it could take many seconds (or even minutes) to return an error if someone passes a 100GB string as `input`, despite the fact that it was already known after reading the first 256 bytes that an error should be returned. On the other hand, if you write:

```
if (strnlen(input, 256) >= 256) return error_code;
```

then the function can always return quickly. Note that this kind of transformation could actually be applied automatically by the compiler; in the future, with some luck, it might be.

Comment: +1 for the fact that if you're checking the length of a string for validation purposes, it makes sense to stop scanning if it already exceeded the max length you're willing to deal with.

Answer (score 4):

strnlen() is a more secure version of strlen().

Suppose you have a buffer for a c-string where for a reason or another there is no ending '\0'.  strlen() would overflow over the limits of the buffer.  With a little luck it could segfault, but more probably, it will return an erroneously huge length.  The remainder of your code could cause errors if using this length.

With strnlen() you limit the risks by limiting the length to be at most the length of the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

The use is to determine the length of a zero terminated string in a buffer of known size.

Edit: This is different to strlen in the case that there is no terminating zero inside that buffer. By design (buffer is just full) or by accident (Forgot the terminator, or got hacked, ...)

Comment: Well it isn't, actually, it is to determine the length of a string terminated either by a null or a length, whichever comes first.